# Recursion the number of multiplications used in 2 exercise. Have found 2 different answers

Tags: recursion, discrete-mathematics

First let me say this is a problem for my discrete structure class. I wasn't sure if I should post it here or math overflow.

> How does the number of multiplications used by the algorithm in Exercise 24 compare to the number of multiplications used by Algorithm 2 to evaluate
>   a^2^n ?  Just to be clear: the order of evaluation is **2^n**; then raise **a** to that power.

First let me state exercise 24 and algorithm 2.

> ex 24: Devise a recursive algorithm to find a^2^n, where **a** is a real number and **n** is a positive integer. [Hint:Use the equality a^2^(n+1) = (a^2^n)^2.]
>
> The answer is:
>
> ```
> procedure twopower(n: positive integer, a: real number)
> if n=1 return a^2
> else
>     return twopower(n-1, a)^2
> ```
>
> > ALGORITHM 2 A Recursive Algorithm for Computing a^n.
>
> ```
> procedure power (a: nonzero real number, n: nonnegative integer)
> if n= 0 then return 1
> else return a * power (a, n−1)
> ```
>
> {output is a^n}

I have found two different solutions from Chegg textbook solutions and from a solution manual. I'm not sure how the authors come up with each, and I'm unsure if they are both correct.
>
Algorithm 2 uses 2^n multiplications by a, one for each factor of a in the product a^2^n The algorithm in Exercise 24, based on squaring, uses only **n** multiplications (each of which is a multiplication of a number by itself). For instance, to compute a^2^4= a^16, this algorithm will compute a*a= a^2 (one multiplication), then a^2. a^2 = a^4 (a second multiplication), then a^4. a^4 = as (a third),and finally as. as = a^16 (a fourth multiplication). (Solutions Manual)
>

Chegg solutions states for ex 24 uses 2^n multiplications; for algorithm 2, it states the number of multiplications used is n. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I like messages being properly formatted. "used by the al-gorithm" - what is "al-gorithm"? I know about algorithms, but I never heard about "al-gorithms".  What is "finda"? Why part of your message is in yellow color?  You don't care about people who are going to read your question, why should we bother to answer it?

Comment: Not sure exactly why its coming out like that, it's my second time posting a question. With that said I am fairly new here.I have posted this message in chegg and it came out just fine. I reposted here using copy and paste and it came out terrible. I understand  "al-gorithm" is not properly formatted, but im sure you know it  means algorithm. Now that I mentioned that I'm new here, is up to whoever if they are willing to help or not. It's real funny how people are eager to criticise rather than help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both solutions are correct -- when called with the proper arguments.  The first one computes **a^2^n** given **a** and **n**.  It does this by squaring the number **n** times.

Algorithm 2 can return the same result, but must be called with **a** and **2^n**.  Yes, it performs **n** multiplications -- but it's not the same **n**.

Do you need to trace the operation?  If so, simply convert both algorithms to your favourite language, stick a tracing print statement into each, and run them.

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot. I thought both answers might be correct.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.